# Replace ip address with hostname using sed or other command-line tool

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

I have a command that outputs something like this:

```
192.168.1.1        182
192.168.1.10       300
192.168.4.50       64
```

I want to pipe this through sed or some other linux command-line tool and replace the IP addresses with their hostname from the 'host ' command, like this:

```
web.hostname.com     182
db.hostname.com      300
search.hostname.com  64
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: what's the command? a lot of existing net tools have a switch to do names vs ips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks a bit tricky, but should do what you need:

```
your_command | while read HOST NUM; do host $HOST | tr "\n" " "; echo $NUM; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out how to get sed to use the evaluation of a command (in backticks) in the replace string and pass it one of the matched subexpressions as an argument, but maybe someone else can.

If you are in bash, you could pipe it into this:

```
while read ip whatever ; do hostname=`host $ip | grep pointer` ; \
if [ -n "$hostname" ] ; then echo `host $ip` $whatever | \
sed 's/\(^.* pointer \)\(.*\)\./\2/g'  ; else echo $ip $whatever ; fi ; done
```

(This tries to pull the hostname out of the response, and leave the ip address numeric if the result of the lookup isn't a hostname)